# Initializing Cloud.Firestore from Xamarin Mono

Tags: firebase, xamarin, google-cloud-firestore, xamarin.android, mono

I have used the model described here
https://furotmark.github.io/2021/12/29/Firestore-Credential-Initialization-With-AppSettings.html
to serialize Firebase credentials.  That is working just fine.

Then I tried to create the DB with

```
        string firebaseJson = fsi.Serialize(); // this works fine

        FirestoreDbBuilder fsDBBuilder = new FirestoreDbBuilder
        {
            ProjectId = fbSettings.ProjectId,
            JsonCredentials = firebaseJson // <-- service account json file
        }; // this works fine

        FirestoreDb db = fsDBBuilder.Build(); // this line crashes[enter image description here][2]
```

I get an exception
System.IO.InvalidDataException: 'Invalid sequence, too long.'

Any help would be appreciated.

Stack Trace:

at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Pkcs8+Asn1+Decoder.ReadSequence () [0x0001f] in C:\Apiary\2022-02-18.09-47-54\Src\Support\Google.Apis.Auth\OAuth2\Pkcs8.cs:141 \n  at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Pkcs8+Asn1+Decoder.Decode () [0x00046] in C:\Apiary\2022-02-18.09-47-54\Src\Support\Google.Apis.Auth\OAuth2\Pkcs8.cs:70 \n  at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Pkcs8+Asn1.Decode (System.Byte[] bs) [0x00000] in C:\Apiary\2022-02-18.09-47-54\Src\Support\Google.Apis.Auth\OAuth2\Pkcs8.cs:215 \n  at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Pkcs8.DecodeRsaParameters (System.String pkcs8PrivateKey) [0x0006f] in C:\Apiary\2022-02-18.09-47-54\Src\Support\Google.Apis.Auth\OAuth2\Pkcs8.cs:236 \n  at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.ServiceAccountCredential+Initializer.FromPrivateKey (System.String privateKey) [0x00000] in C:\Apiary\2022-02-18.09-47-54\Src\Support\Google.Apis.Auth\OAuth2\ServiceAccountCredential.cs:123 \n  at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.DefaultCredentialProvider.CreateServiceAccountCredentialFromParameters (Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.JsonCredentialParameters credentialParameters) [0x00066] in C:\Apiary\2022-02-18.09-47-54\Src\Support\Google.Apis.Auth\OAuth2\DefaultCredentialProvider.cs:260 \n  at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.DefaultCredentialProvider.CreateDefaultCredentialFromParameters (Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.JsonCredentialParameters credentialParameters) [0x00000] in C:\Apiary\2022-02-18.09-47-54\Src\Support\Google.Apis.Auth\OAuth2\DefaultCredentialProvider.cs:209 \n  at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.DefaultCredentialProvider.CreateDefaultCredentialFromJson (System.String json) [0x0001b] in C:\Apiary\2022-02-18.09-47-54\Src\Support\Google.Apis.Auth\OAuth2\DefaultCredentialProvider.cs:203 \n  at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleCredential.FromJson (System.String json) [0x00000] in C:\Apiary\2022-02-18.09-47-54\Src\Support\Google.Apis.Auth\OAuth2\GoogleCredential.cs:169 \n  at Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.ClientBuilderBase`1[TClient].GetGoogleCredential () [0x00000] in /_/Google.Api.Gax.Grpc/ClientBuilderBase.cs:434 \n  at Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.ClientBuilderBase`1[TClient].GetChannelCredentials () [0x00000] in /*/Google.Api.Gax.Grpc/ClientBuilderBase.cs:410 \n  at Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.ClientBuilderBase`1[TClient].CreateCallInvoker () [0x0004f] in /*/Google.Api.Gax.Grpc/ClientBuilderBase.cs:370 \n  at Google.Cloud.Firestore.V1.FirestoreClientBuilder.BuildImpl () [0x00006] in /*/apis/Google.Cloud.Firestore.V1/Google.Cloud.Firestore.V1/FirestoreClient.g.cs:405 \n  at Google.Cloud.Firestore.V1.FirestoreClientBuilder.Build () [0x00001] in /*/apis/Google.Cloud.Firestore.V1/Google.Cloud.Firestore.V1/FirestoreClient.g.cs:391 \n  at Google.Cloud.Firestore.FirestoreDbBuilder.Build () [0x00056] in /_/apis/Google.Cloud.Firestore/Google.Cloud.Firestore/FirestoreDbBuilder.cs:105 \n  at FBCloudNotes.MainActivity.OnCreate (Android.OS.Bundle savedInstanceState) [0x0007e] in D:\Sam\Teaching\Android\Code\FBCloudNotes\FBCloudNotes\MainActivity.cs:61 "

Comment: Please post the *full* stack trace - at the moment we don't know which line is causing the problem.

Comment: Posted the call stack.  Thanks

Comment: Okay - so it looks like the code is throwing here: https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/blob/main/Src/Support/Google.Apis.Auth/OAuth2/Pkcs8.cs#L141 You've posted this with Xamarin tags - are you able to reproduce the issue with a simple .NET console app? Are you certain that `firebaseJson` is correct? (Obviously you shouldn't post that, given that it's sensitive, but you could check in the debugger that it looks like you'd expect it to.) You can remove the Firestore part of this by just using `GoogleCredential.FromJson(firebaseJson)` - that's what's failing, after all.